# Using make_grid to preview a dataset is generating exceptions

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to display images using `make_grid()` and cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
class CustomDS(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pil_objs, transform=None):
        self.pil_objs = pil_objs
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pil_objs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        pil_img = self.pil_objs[idx]
        if self.transform:
            pil_img = self.transform(pil_img)
        return pil_img

image_transformations = Compose([
    v2.Resize((224, 224)),
    v2.PILToTensor(),
    v2.Normalize(mean=[0.485,  0.456,  0.406], std=[0.229,  0.224,  0.225]),
])

image_dataset = CustomDS(pil_objs, image_transformations)
image_dataloader = DataLoader(image_dataset, batch_size=IN_BATCH_SIZES, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

first_batch = next(iter(image_dataloader))
grid = make_grid(first_batch, nrow=8)
to_pil = ToPILImage()(grid)
to_pil.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 10
>    5     plt.show()
>    7 # Assuming you have already defined your DataLoader as 'image_dataloader'
>    8 
>    9 # Get the first batch from the DataLoader
---> 10 first_batch = next(iter(image_dataloader))
```

Additional notes

- the pil_objs is a list of 4,000+ Pil Image Objects
- `len(image_dataloader.dataset)`  returns the correct number of images
- `len(image_dataloader)` returns the number of batches based on the batch_size and qty of images

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [`PILToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.pil_to_tensor.html?highlight=pil_to_tensor#torchvision.transforms.functional.pil_to_tensor) operator doesn't cast the tensor and keeps the same dtype. You may instead use [`ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor.html?highlight=to_tensor#torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor) instead which is generally preferred:

```
image_transformations = Compose([
    v2.Resize((224, 224)),
    v2.ToTensor(),
    v2.Normalize(mean=[0.485,  0.456,  0.406], std=[0.229,  0.224,  0.225]),
])
```